Argo workflow input parameters with value from SQS payload
I want to trigger an Argo workflow by reading value from SQS event source's payload.
For example, my workflow template accepts an input parameter "date". I need to listen to AWS SQS and extract this value from my sqs payload and then trigger workflow by passing this value as input parameter.
Sample sqs payload:
{"date" : "2024-01-01"}.
I am able to create workflow with input parameter & sqs event source, but I am missing the part where I need to extract the value of date from my incoming message and pass it on to workflow's parameter.
In below code, I need to pass the value from my dependency 'dependency-abc's payload which is {"date":"2024-01-01"} to 'input.parameters.date'
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Sensor
metadata:
  name: aws-sqs
spec:
  template:
    serviceAccountName: daadi-argo-sa
  dependencies:
    - name: dependency-abc
      eventSourceName: aws-sqs
      eventName: event-abc
  triggers:
    - template:
        name: sqs-workflow
        k8s:
          operation: create
          source:
            resource:
              apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
              kind: Workflow
              metadata:
                generateName: aws-sqs-workflow-
              spec:
                serviceAccountName: argo-sa
                entrypoint: whalesay
                arguments:
                  parameters:
                  - name: date
                templates:
                - name: whalesay
                  inputs:
                    parameters:
                    - name: message
                  container:
                    image: docker/whalesay:latest
                    command: [cowsay]
                    args: ["{{inputs.parameters.date}}"]
        


The parameters, src, dependencyName, dataKey and dest need to be specified within k8s. These source and destination parameters map the dependency payload to the workflow parameters.
k8s:
  operation: create
  source:
    resource:
      apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
      kind: Workflow
      metadata:
        generateName: aws-sqs-workflow-
      spec:
        serviceAccountName: argo-sa
        entrypoint: whalesay
        arguments:
          parameters:
            - name: date
        templates:
          - name: whalesay
            inputs:
              parameters:
                - name: message
            container:
              image: docker/whalesay:latest
              command: [cowsay]
              args: ["{{inputs.parameters.date}}"]
  parameters: # Parameters to pass to the Workflow
    - src: # Source of the data
        dependencyName: dependency-abc # Event source dependency
        dataKey: date # Selector for payload data (date)
      dest: spec.arguments.parameters.0.value # Destination for data selection (first parameter - date)

References:

https://github.com/argoproj/argo-events/blob/master/examples/sensors/aws-sqs.yaml
https://argoproj.github.io/argo-events/APIs/#argoproj.io/v1alpha1.StandardK8STrigger
https://argoproj.github.io/argo-events/

